# How to get data from form input as it's typed

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I'm not sure this is even possible, but I'm trying to show the input data in a 'preview' section before the form is actually submitted. I've drawn up this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QJNym/)** to help out.

HTML:

```
<form>
  Test:<input type="text" name="test" />
</form>
  <aside class="preview">
    <h5>Preview of Test:</h5>
      <span />
  </aside>
```

JS:

```
iData = $('#test').text();
$('.preview span').html(iData);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvotes? I googled away before asking..

Comment: The downvotes are probably because the question doesn't show any research effort (which is what the tooltip for downvoting states). You probably should have included an example of what you have tried in the question directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use keydown and input with a timer to prevent duplicate and allow value to change on keydowns. Also catches paste cut and delete both with context menu and keyboard shortcuts. keydown is more for compatibility with old browsers than anything else, input catches most of it.

```
$("input[name='test']").on("keydown input",function(){
    var self = this;
    clearTimeout($(this).data("timer"));
    $(this).data("timer", setTimeout(function(){
        $('.preview span').html(self.value);
    },1));
});
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QJNym/17/)</kbd>

Comment: This is the most elegant solution presented. Thanks!

Comment: By using keydown/input rather than keyup and change, the results are instant. I rarely see a need to use keyup.

Comment: This seems to create a load or something (try typing in the input box then trying to select the jQuery). It fades after a while. Is this something I should be concerned about? Seems like it may be causing an endless loop, and multiplied by several inputs that may be bad news, right?

Comment: I'm not seeing what you're seeing, for example, only one setTmeout is completing for each action: http://jsfiddle.net/QJNym/28/

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this is what you want..

but using `keyup()` and `val()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name="test"]').keyup(function(){ //using attribute selector here since you havenot defined id for the input
    $('.preview span').html($(this).val()) ; 
  });
})
```

you can define the an id to your input and use id selector..

example:

**html**

```
<form>
 Test:<input type="text" id="test" name="test" />
</form>
<aside class="preview">
  <h5>Preview of Test:</h5>
  <span />
</aside>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').keyup(function(){ 
    $('.preview span').html($(this).val()) ; 
  });
})
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/QJNym/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.keyup()`

```
$("input[name='test']").keyup(function() {
    $('.preview span').html(this.value);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/QJNym/13/

Comment: Hmm, cool approach, but that means that the last character will not be visible until another keystroke is made.

Comment: Also, the last character doesn't ever show, unless you type an extra character. Perhaps `.keyup`?

Comment: @asawyer -- would chaining a blur function to this help? this way it would capture the pasted input once the focus is lost?

Comment: It would help, but then it wouldn't be "as it's typed", it would be "after the input loses focus"

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="test"]').keyup(function(){
var inputValue = $(this).val();
$('.preview span').text(inputValue);
});
```